# Why would an api query return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I call this api using npm request I get back an empty array. I've loaded request and defined the value of content at the top of the page (not shown here). I also changed the api key here. None of those three things are the issue (request, content, or the api key).

When I run the debugger with `Chrome://inspect` it's showing a failure at the err/response that reads:

> err = null, response = IncomingMessage {_readableState: ReadableState,
>   readable: false, domain: null, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 4, …}, body
>   = '

Here's the code:

```
function concertThis(){


  var queryUrl = "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/" + content + 
  "/events?app_id=api_key"

  console.log(queryUrl);

  request(queryUrl, function(err, response, body){
    if(!err && response.statusCode === 200){
        debugger;

       console.log("-------");
       console.log(JSON.parse(body));  

      }
    })

 }
```

This is what the result in my terminal looks like:

```
$ node liri.js concert-this mumford and sons
https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/mumford+and+sons/events? 
app_id=api_key
-------
[]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you provide network response screens ?

Comment: What exactly is that `request()` function? *edit* ah it's the `npm` "request" client module, OK

Comment: What are you expecting it to return? I get the same response if I execute this request via the address bar of a browser.

Comment: @jake11 I just added console.log(response.statusCode) and it returned 200

Comment: Note that using that API from a browser and using it from Node are very significantly different things.

Comment: `err = null, response = IncomingMessage {_readableState: ReadableState, readable: false, domain: null, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 4, …}, body = '` that doesn't tell me much man

Comment: @RyanC I'm expecting it to return JSON data

Comment: @austin.walker An empty array is JSON data. I mean exactly what are you expecting? Do you have a reason to believe that there should be more meaningful data in the response for this request?

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it figured out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this out using the [bandsintown api in-documentation execute](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Bandsintown/PublicAPI/3.0.0#/artist%20events/artistEvents) and it returned an empty array. Could it be the case that Mumford and Sons does not have any upcoming events? Have you tried a different band?

[Here is an example](https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/shawnmendes/events?app_id=8fb65637e592547afe5889341ee4cf88) of Shawn Mendes who has events and there is info in the response.

Comment: That was it! I'd only been testing with mumford and sons.......... Thanks @Rastalamm

Comment: Woo hoo! If this the best solution to your issue can you please mark it as the accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Also, you should reset/change your API key

Comment: Will do. Thanks again